# corregir un codigo con error de sintaxis en INSERT INTO

Tags: .htaccess, ms-access, ms-access-2010, microsoft-office, office365

CurrentDb.OpenRecordset "INSERT INTO [Tipos_de_sexo] (Tipos de sexo)'" & VALUES & "', '" & NewData & "' dbFailOnError)"

Comment: Parece que hay dos `VALUES` y una sola columna. También, deberías evitar los nombres de columnas con espacio en las tablas y, si mal no recuerdo, en ese caso deberías ponerlo así: `[Tipos de sexo]`. En las preguntas aquí, pon siempre el mensaje de error completo, es un valor precioso para resolver problemas. Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Como puedo observar tu  insert tiene 3 columnas, asegúrate de poner los nombres correctos mas su valores, recuerda los String van en comillas simples `''` y datos enteros sin ellos, recuerda cada tipo de dato es especial.

```
INSERT INTO Nombre_Base.Nombre_Tabla (columa1,columna2, columna3) Values 
('valor1', 'valor2','valor3')
```